# PHP FuelSDK - ET_Client Internal Server Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

We use ExactTarget PHP SDK version "FuelSDK-PHP-v0.9". The error reported was:

> Error: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided.: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided, requestToken response:{"message":"Internal Server Error","errorcode":0,"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm"}

which comes from https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP/blob/master/src/ET_Client.php#L263 line.

This happens very random and does not happen every day. So that is really confusing to nail down the exact issue.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?